# illuminance on a slope plane

Tags: visible-light, lightning

I am trying to understand the illuminance from an extended source(sky dome) on an inclined plane. The article I am reading has beautifully explained it. Yet I don't understand the angles and boundary used thoroughly. It describes the angles as this:

"σ: angle within a segment of sky"
I believe this is the same as the azimuth angle of the infinitesimal path of the light source, is that right?

"Φ: angle between normal to the plane and a segment of sky". this I think is clear.

[image]

Why the outer integral boundary(which regards Φ) is from -S to pi/2? Should it not be from 0(horizon) to (pi/2+S)? But trying this would result in a different answer to the integral.

Also Is pi/2 at zenith and -S from below the horizon? Or zenith considered to be at 0 and pi/2 at horizon? I seem not to figure out these boundaries and would appreciate any idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Relative to the normal $N_s$ of the plane, $\Phi$ goes from $-S$ (reaching the sky horizon) to $+\pi/2$ (when it is parallel to the plane. Further, it would be on the back side of the plane, which must not count).